# Use repl for Hy in Emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, emacs24, hy

I have successfully installed `hy-mode` from https://github.com/hylang/hy-mode. I now can open a `.hy` file in emacs and have syntax highlighting, and editing with `paredit` is a joy.

I however, don't know how to start a REPL. At the bottom of the github readme, it says:

> When in hy-mode, you can launch a Hy REPL by launching a Lisp inferior
>   process
>
> M-x lisp-inferior-process

That function, however, is not defined for me. What else do I need to install or check to be able to use the repl for Hy?

I am currently using:
GNU Emacs 24.3.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried to set `inferior-lisp-program` to `"hy"` and then doing M-x run-lisp?

This is the standard way (or maybe just the "way I know about") of having an inferior lisp process.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 1.0.4 of hy-mode, you can start a hy repl buffer in Emacs using `M-x run-hy` or use the default key binding of `C-c C-z`.

In any Emacs mode, including hy-mode, you can use `M-x describe-mode` or the default key binding of `C-h m` to show key bindings for the current mode.